# Azure Storage and Conditional Replace/Merge

Tags: c#, azure, insert-update, upsert, azure-table-storage

In Azure table storage's batch save operation, is there an efficient way to replace certain properties on an entity if it already exists; but update all properties for new entities?

Here is the scenario that I am talking about.

I have an entity called Order

```
public class Order : TableEntity
{
    public Order(String department, string orderId)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = department;
        this.RowKey = orderId;
    }

    public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
    public String CreatedBy {get; set;}

    public DateTime UpdatedOn {get; set;}
    public String UpdatedBy {get; set;}

    //Class contains other properties which could add up to 1MB
}
```

**Scenario**

1. Azure Table Storage has order entities with RowKeys [0..100]
2. My API receives an upsert request for orders with RowKeys [50..150].
3. In a single batch transaction I need to update certain properties on orders [50-100] and create new order entities [101-150] on azure.
4. **Note:** On the existing orders [50..100], all properties except the CreatedOn, CreatedBy, PartitionKey and RowKey needs to be updated.

Can I do it in a single step without reading contents from the Table Store?

Here is a one way to do it (very rough pseudo code)

```
function Upsert(Dictionary<String, Order> ordersInput)
{
    //1. Read existing ordersInput from database
    var existingOrders = Retrieve(ordersInput.Values);

    //2. Update 'ordersInput' with existing data
    foreach(var existingOrder in existingOrders)
    {
        if(ordersInput.ContainsKey(existingOrder.RowKey)
        {
            ordersInput[existingOrder.RowKey].CreatedOn = existingOrder.CreatedOn;
            ordersInput[existingOrder.RowKey].CreatedBy = existingOrder.CreatedBy;
        }
    }

    //Save all merged orders to Azure
    SaveToAzure(existingOrders);
}
```

The issue I have with the above approach is that each order entity is 1 MB in size and reading all entities bogs down the API save operation.

Is there a more efficient way to perform the conditional merge entirely on azure?

I was also thinking about doing a batch insert in the following way

1. Do a batch **Insert** on all orders
2. If the previous step fails with "**The specified entity already exists**", then create two new batches (one with existing row keys and other with new ones) and take care of each one individually

(The above approach sounds hacky and I think it might cause a bunch of concurrency issues)

Comment: I used a combination of Query projection & insertormerge

Answer (score 5):

Azure Table Storage natively support `Upsert` operation via [`InsertOrReplace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertorreplace.aspx) and [`InsertOrMerge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insertormerge.aspx) functions. `InsertOrReplace` will replace an entity completely with the new entity if it exists otherwise it will create a new one. `InsertOrMerge` will change the properties of an existing entity which are present in the new entity if the entity with the same PartitionKey/RowKey exists otherwise it will create a new one.

**UPDATE**

Here's an alternate approach. A few things you can do:

1. **Query Projection**: Query projection allows you to fetch only certain attributes of an entity. So when you're fetching existing entities, you only fetch `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` so that you can determine if an entity already exists or not. This would considerably reduce the response payload.
2. **Nullable fields**: Since you don't want to update `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy` fields for existing entities, you would need to make them nullable especially `CreatedOn`.

Based on this, you would first fetch the existing entities. Retrieve operation would only return `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` (using query projection technique). Then you would loop through the `ordersInput` and see if the entity exists. If the entity exists, then you will set `CreatedOn` and `CreatedBy` as `null` and mark that entity to be `Merged`. If the entity does not exist, you will set all the properties and mark that entity to be `Inserted`. Then you will send this batch request to table service.

Comment: I did explore the InsertOrMerge operation, but it does not work for the scenario that I had mentioned. Is there a way to tell InsertOrMerge to skip updating a specific property if the entity is already on Azure (e.g. Created By Fields should not be overwritten if the entity is already on Azure, even on passing a new value)